# Getting PK columns from ColumnFamily columnFamily, ByteBuffer key Cassandra triggers

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I am new to cassandra triggers. I am still ramping up. I could find a way to extract value out for a given ByteBuffer key, but do not know how to get the "name" of the actual primary key column

```
public static String getKeyText(ColumnFamily columnFamily, ByteBuffer key) {
  CFMetaData cfm = columnFamily.metadata();
  String key_data = cfm.getKeyValidator().getString(key);
}
```

Any idea on how to get just the key column name?

Any pointers are highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if this what you mean, but you can get the name of the partition keys from `columnFamily.partitionKeyColumns()` the ColumnDefinition's have a `name` field thats readable. There may be more than one depending on schema

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/config/CFMetaData.java#L797

Comment: Thanks that's what I am looking for. Though it was my stupidity for not taking a look at all the APIs